# Codeigniter, how to save uploaded file to new folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, ftp, routes

I'm adding onto an admin CMS, and need image files uploaded to save to a separate folder I have specified. I can save them to a predefined folder of another controller, but how do I save them to the new folder I have created?

When I try, it doesn't allow it. I know it has something to do with routing, but where to I change codeigniter to allow that? I have looked in config/routes.php and don't see it listed there.

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: accept if you found your solutions.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
function uploadFile($uploadFile,$filetype,$folder,$fileName='')
{
$resultArr = array();
$config['max_size'] = '1024000';
if($filetype == 'img')  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'.$folder.'/';

if($fileName != "")
    $config['file_name'] = $fileName;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload($uploadFile))
{
    $resultArr['success'] = false;
    $resultArr['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
}   else    {
    $resArr = $this->upload->data();
    $resultArr['success'] = true;
    $resultArr['path'] = "uploads/".$folder."/".$resArr['file_name'];
}
return $resultArr;
 }
```